# Correct way to install latex packages on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: texlive, linux, tlmgr

I really want to use TikZiT because it makes drawing graphs easy. However, I have run into a problem while trying to install additional latex packages in Debian. I used apt to install texlive, but when I try using tlmgr, it gives me "tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)". I read that I could resolve this by installing texlive manually, but that sounds way too error-prone and over complicated considering I just want get a PDF of a single graph. It also sounds like a really stupid idea to have manually installed stuff next to automatically installed stuff. I'm wondering if there is a "correct" way to install aditional packages, without installing texlive itself manually.

Comment: If the package was in the texlive 2018 that you have you will be able to get it via apt by installing one of the texlive collections, if you mean you want a new latex package not in texlive 2018 then you may need to get it from ctan and install locally

Comment: Debian has various other apt packages that contain LaTeX packages, such as `texlive-latex-extra` and `texlive-latex-recommended`. The package `texlive-full` contains almost everything, but is quite large. See https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=texlive&searchon=names&suite=buster&section=all for a list for Debian 10. If you just want to install a particular single extra LaTeX package, or a package or version that is not in any apt package, then you can install that package and its dependencies manually from CTAN.

Comment: Install a complete vanilla texlive take some time to download  but is easy,  and imho, a better solution  that  mess with  several  `.deb` packages that maybe are a bit/very outdated.

Comment: @Fran I for one am very happy with my `.deb` packages :) Installing vanilla texlive may be easy, but installing with `apt` is absolutely trivial. No manual downloading, no following instructions, no thinking about repositories or compiling or paths or permissions, no version conflicts, no learning to use yet another package manager, `apt` takes care of all of that automatically and seamlessly. The meta-package `texlive-full` has almost everything, and if there is a tool missing (such as `latexmk`) then `apt` tells you which line to type (`apt install latexmk`) when you try to use it.

Comment: And for the updates: it is true that the `.deb` packages are outdated (Ubuntu for example has a two-year release cycle and packages are frozen in between) but this has never caused a problem for me in day-to-day tasks (it's a different story for answering TeX.SE questions, where I regularly have to check the latest package versions...). So for many use cases I think Debian packages are an easy and sufficient solution.

Comment: @Marijn I am Linux user since 1995, and a Debian/Ubuntu/mint user   (exclusively,, no Window in another partition) for two decades now, since Potato times. I know very well  the advantages of  .deb packages (in fact apt-get the reason to used that Linux distros),  but in some cases as TeX Live, and R, you can survive to an installl/update without apt, and this have some advantages. On the other hand, as survivor to many  debian-like distro updates, I can assure that  .deb packages are  not always free of  problems (well, if you comfort zone is Debian stable, maybe..).